# How to access method properties at compile-time?

Tags: java, reflection, refactoring

I would like to access the usual reflection properties of a specific method without relying on `String`s.

Is there any way to get from the method-*Identifier* to its reflection properties, like parameter types?

```
void run() {
    java.lang.reflect.Method m = myMethod.getMethod(); // how? 
    Class<?>[] argClasses = m.getParameterTypes();
}

int myMethod(String arg) {
   // ...
}
```

The piece `myMethod.getMethod()` is not valid. It is my way of saying "get from the method-identifier to the `java.lang.reflect.Method` object".

The string-way I do not want to use would be similar to `m = getClass().getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", ...)`

I use `myMethod` like a regular *identifier* and not as a String, i.e. `"myMethod"`. I think this would be beneficial for refactoring, where someone renames `myMethod` to `hisMethod` -- the relation via the `String`-name would break, where the relation via the identifier would be refactored as well.

Comment: I've come up similar problem a lot of times and the solution is to implement a custom annotation processor that traverses through given package and generates static meta-model classes about classes with some properties.

Comment: @kocko I see. I feared as much. Strange, since the method-name *is* an identifier. It could be used, couldn't I? I don't like the "accompanying classes" solution much.

Answer (score 0):

In java methods aren't first class citizens, so there is no solutions in Java for this problem.

Yet I had a similar problem and forged a small tool named [picklock](https://github.com/almondtools/picklock) for this purpose.

Comment: Quite nice, although not exactly what I need. Since I don't want "access myMethod like a java method" but like a variable. You said it yourself, methods are nit 1st class citizens -- I wonder why.

Comment: Sorry, after reviewing I see that your problem is not so similar as I first supposed. I removed the 'howto' section, to be more concise.